# File developer cannot be verified error

Tags: macos, mac, file-permissions

I'm trying to run my project's executable on macOS, but I have this error message [“_pickle.cpython-38-darwin.so” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.]

- Error message shown in the picture below :

[image: Error message]

I go to System preferences > Security & Privacy > General tab, I find this message ["_pickle.cpython-38-darwin.so " was blocked from use because it's not from an identified developer]

- Message is shown in the picture below:

[image: Security & Privacy message]

I press "Allow Anyway" to approve this file,
Then the first error message appears for a different file, I approve it as I did with the previous file and another error message appear for a different file and so on for about 25 - 30 different files.
Then finally when I approve them the executable runs well.

Is there any way to tell the macOS to trust these files without asking the user to approve them manually? On the current MAC or any new MAC will run the executable?

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

The problem happens because my MAC machine adds this attribute "com.apple.quarantine" to my files when it's downloaded from the internet.
You can view if this attribute exists on your file using the command: **ls -lR@ fileName**

The solution is to delete "com.apple.quarantine" attribute from these files
you can do that by executing the bellow shell command at the root folder contains your files,
So this attribute will be deleted from all your files

shell command:  **xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine the_root_folder_contains_your_files**

Comment: Best option for when you have a folder full of binary files that need to be unblocked. Can't believe I had to search this long to find a solution. All the other answers and blogs I saw point out the UI way which doesn't have an option to add an exception for a folder. Thanks for taking the time to share this.

Answer (score 2):

Try right-click, Open.
idk if that will allow all daughter processes at one time or whether it will still repeat.

[Apple KB - Open a Mac app from an unidentified developer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac)

Otherwise you need an app to be signed & notarized.

[Apple KB - Signing Your Apps for Gatekeeper](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem happens to 36 files so It's hard to open them one by one, 
I found the answer to my question and I will post it in the answers
I appreciate your help, thanks.